# Usages d'« usage » et d'« utilisation », quel mot utiliser?

Tags: choix-de-mot, vocabulaire

Il m'a semblé voir beaucoup d'utilisations incorrectes de ces deux mots sur le site.
N'étant pas sûr de moi, j'aimerais une clarification quant à leurs usages.

Et bien sûr, indiquez-moi si je les ai inversés ici, ou si j'en ai fait une mauvaise utilisation… ou mauvais usage ! ;-)

Comment: J'hésite un peu à rajouter le tag `usage`...

Comment: @Joubarc. Je ne pense pas que cette distinction soit souvent d'usage dans l'[tag:usage] *du français*. Je ne suis donc pas en faveur de l'ajout de ce tag.

Comment: Si j'étais **vraiment** en faveur de l'ajout du tag, ce serait déjà fait :-)

Comment: @Joubarc & Stéphane: *en faveur*, c'est pas du English, ça ?

Comment: @Benjol [non](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faveur), [pas vraiment](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/fr/wiki/en_faveur_de). Je gage que l'expression anglaise vient du français à la base.

Comment: A noter: Si on remplace « utiliser » par « user » dans le titre de la page, ça n'a plus de sens.

Comment: @Joubarc, ah, j'apprends quelque chose. *(Gngng, my &nbsp; got encoded)*

Comment: @Benjol Moi aussi, et ça tombe bien, c'est pour ça qu'on est là.

Comment: Alors parle-t-on de "l'usage d'un bâtiment scolaire" ou "l'utilisation d'un bâtiment scolaire"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Le terme `usage` a quatre emplois en français, dont deux peuvent se regrouper. Certains de ces emplois sont relatifs à l'utilisation, mais avec certaines nuances :

#### 1/ Le terme `usage` peut signifier l'habitude

> L'usage du chapeau n'est plus très courant de nos jours.

En ce cas, on ne peut pas *nécessairement* substituer directement l'`usage` par l'`utilisation` : « l'utilisation du chapeau », pour signifier « l'usage du chapeau », serait correct au niveau du sens de la phrase, mais serait maladroit, voire incorrect, d'un point de vue de l'usage de la langue.

Il arrive cependant que la substitution soit correcte : 
« l'utilisation du préservatif est courante de nos jours », pour signifier « l'usage du préservatif est courant de nos jours », est tout à fait correct et habituel.

#### 2/ Il peut signifier les règles établies

> Veuillez porter une tenue correcte. C'est l'usage ici.

Cet emploi du mot `usage` est proche de celui vu en 1/, si ce n'est qu'il donne une dimension obligatoire à cette habitude. Le *Trésor de la langue française* les regroupe d'ailleurs dans la [définition du mot (sens A)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/usage).

Enfin, cet emploi peut n'avoir aucun rapport avec le fait d'utiliser :

> Se coucher tard n'est pas d'usage, chez nous.

#### 3/ Il peut signifier la capacité à utiliser

> Il avait perdu l'usage de sa voix.

Ceci ne peut se substituer par l'utilisation, mais uniquement par la capacité, la possibilité, d'effectuer cette utilisation: « il ne pouvait plus utiliser sa voix », « il avait perdu toute capacité à le faire », etc.

#### 4/ Et il peut signifier le fait d'utiliser

D'après le *Trésor de la langue française*,

- [`usage`](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/usage) se rapporte pour ce sens précis (B.1.a) au « fait de se servir de quelque chose, d'appliquer un procédé, une technique, de faire agir un objet, une matière selon leur nature, leur fonction propre afin d'obtenir un effet qui permette de satisfaire un besoin. Synon. emploi, utilisation. » ;
- tandis qu'[`utilisation`](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/utilisation) se définit comme « action, manière d'utiliser. Synon. emploi. »

On voit que les deux termes sont synonymes d'emploi.
D'un point de vue de l'usage (de la langue j'entends :p), en France, j'entends souvent « utiliser un outil » ou « faire usage d'un outil ».

Sans que ceci ne soit une définition formelle, j'ai l'impression que la nuance se situe surtout au niveau de langage que l'on souhaite donner à sa phrase.

Ainsi:

- « Fais usage d'un marteau ! » se comprendra, ne sera pas perçu comme incorrect, mais sera un peu surprenant. Le niveau de langage est un peu haut pour cette phrase impérative simple. Ce niveau de langage explique sans doute pourquoi dans la presse, au contraire, « le policier a dû faire usage de son arme » est une phrase tout à fait habituelle tandis que « le policier a dû utiliser son arme » ne se lit presque jamais.
- « Il utilise son marteau » ne choque pas du tout, c'est même très courant d'entendre cela. « Il fait usage de son marteau » pourrait se lire dans un roman, ou bien s'entendre dans une circonstance où un langage plus soutenu s'impose, comme par exemple une plaidoirie de Cour.
- Enfin, « utilise-le à bon escient » ou « fais en bon usage » sont synonymes et se comprennent tous les deux très bien.

« Faire usage » et « utiliser » sont donc interchangeables à mon sens, mais « faire usage » est dans certains cas d'un niveau un peu plus élevé qu'« utiliser ».

Comment: Les deux ne sont pas interchangeable. Remplacer « les usages en vigueur à la cour de France » par « les utilisations en vigueur à la cour de France » n'est pas possible.  Par contre, je pense que tout occurrence d'« utilisation » peut être remplacée par « usage » sans changer le sens (au pire en ajoutant une ambiguïté).

Comment: +1, effectivement : je me limite plus haut à `usage` au sens `emploi`. Pas à `Usage` au sens `us`, `coutumes`, `règles`, etc. Je vais le préciser.

Comment: Personnellement la distinction que j'en faisais avant de poser la question (et j'ai bien fait de la poser !) c'est justement cette impression que tu décris : *utilisation* → emploi précis à un instant/endroit donné, *usage* → pratique habituelle.

Comment: Et c'est exactement là où deux sens de `usage` se rejoignent un peu. Comme le dit @Un francophone, par exemple "les usages en vigueur" signifient "les règles en vigueur"... et en définissent "les pratiques habituelles".

Comment: « J'avais perdu en un moment l'usage de mes sens. » (exemple du TLFi venant d'A. France) « Usage » ne décrit pas une norme, mais le remplacement par « utilisation » ne me conviendrait pas (par « emploi » me gênerais moins).

Comment: Shlublu, tout à fait d'accord. Ce qui me turlupine aussi c'est que *usage*, ou *utilisation*, peuvent chacun désigner deux choses : la façon d'utiliser et le but de l'action. Exemple : « mauvais usage » et « mauvaise utilisation » ont tous les deux deux sens distincts (soit 4 au total).

Comment: @Un francophone Oui, et on est bien dans les mêmes limitations. `Faire usage` dans le sens `faire emploi` est le seul à même de s'échanger directement avec `Utiliser`. "J'avais perdu la capacité d'utiliser mes jambes" et "J'avais perdu l'usage de mes jambes" sont bien équivalents en termes de sens, le second étant d'un niveau un peu plus élevé. De même pour "faire usage de mes jambes était impossible" ou "utiliser mes jambes m'était impossible". C'est assez ténu, en fait :)

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Oui ça rejoint l'impression dont on parlait. Lorsqu'on a « perdu l'usage » cela signifie qu'il n'y aura pas d'utilisations. Si l'*utilisation* est bien une action ponctuelle, « perdre l'utilisation » ne veut rien dire. Et il semble que justement cette expression n'est jamais employée.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez Oui, c'est une autre difficulté... Et `faire bon usage` signifie `utiliser à bon escient`. En fait, je ne crois pas que l'on puisse trouver de limitation formelle à l'un où à l'autre.  Du moins, je n'en ai pas trouvé en recherchant. C'est plutôt une histoire de pratique... d'usage quoi :)

Comment: @Shlublu, on essaie de déterminer les nuances entre entre l'utilisation (ou l'usage -- et je ne ferais pas de différence ici) d'`usage` et d'`utilisation`.  Certaines de tes comparaisons avec des formes employant `utiliser` me semblent non pertinentes, et pour l'avouer créant même de la confusion.

Comment: @Un francophone Le mieux est d'en discuter, qu'en penses-tu ? Tu pourrais ainsi m'indiquer lesquelles, et m'indiquer ce en quoi elles sont non-pertinentes ou erronées.

Answer (score 6):

« Usage » a pour synonyme dans certaines de ses acceptions (voir [le sens B](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/usage)) « utilisation », et ce n'est pas récent à voir la date des exemples donnés.

« Usage » est en plus utilisé pour décrire la pratique généralement admise plutôt qu'un emploi particulier, dans ce cas « utilisation » est inapproprié.

Ce (premier pour le TFLi) sens reste peut-être un peu sous-jacent, car même si le remplacement systématique est possible, il me semble que je préfèrerais « utilisation » à « usage » pour des utilisations rares ou particulières.

Answer (score 1):

L'**usage** désigne les règles usuelles et communément répandues de se servir de cette chose.

L'**utilisation** est la manière d'utiliser quelque chose.