# User et utiliser

Tags: choix-de-mot, vocabulaire

En italien il y a une tendance (à mon avis mauvaise) à préférer *utiliser* à *user*. D'après le dictionnaire il semble qu'en français, la plupart du temps, il est correct de choisir *utiliser*. Mais, quelle est la différence ?

Peut-on dire :

- J'use un marteau.
- Il use trop facilement le mot amour.

Ou est-il mieux d'employer *utiliser* ?

Comment: Seulement parce que il est assez bizzarre. En italien il y a uso (usage, emploi) utilizzo (utilisation) utilizzazione (on ne sait pas que il veut dire vraiment :D)

Comment: Voir, http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/722/usages-dusage-et-dutilisation-quel-mot-utiliser. Et pour faire court: c'est compliqué.

Comment: Merci. J'avais immaginé beacoup de le choses que sont dans cette reponse (il est tres similaire a l'italien). Ce que il me semble different est que en italien on employe "usare" pour tous, et en français non.

Comment: En fait la question pour les verbes est un peu différente car *user* possède le sens supplémentaire associé à l'*usure*. Et d'ailleurs je n'ai pas changé le premier exemple, mais pour éviter ce sens là dans ton premier exemple, il faudrait dire « J'use d'un marteau. ».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D'après le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/), *user **de*** est synonyme de *utiliser* dans certains cas

> A. − User de qqc.
>   1. a) [Le compl. désigne qqc. de concr.] Utiliser quelque chose de façon à obtenir un effet déterminé, la satisfaction d'un besoin.([*user*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/user))

On peut donc dans ce sens dire

> J'use **d**'un marteau.

voire

> Il use trop souvent **du** mot *amour*

Aucun des deux ne sonne très naturel à mon avis<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. « Et je suis **locuteur natif** » fit-il avant de partir en coulisses et d'un rire gras.</sub>

Comment: Enfin utiliser c'est plus "general purpose" que user?

Comment: @Paolo *user de* c'est *utiliser*, en moins général. Par contre *user* a un sens différent.

Answer (score 5):

User quelque chose, c'est en faire usage (sens vieilli), ou détériorer une chose à force de s'en servir.

User de quelque chose c'est s'en servir, ou en faire emploi.

Answer (score 5):

*User* et *utiliser* ne sont pas synonymes ; l'italien *usare* (ou l'anglais *use*) et le français *user* sont des faux amis. En général, le mot français qui correspond à *usare* est *utiliser*, ou *se servir de*. *User* signifie que l'on déteriore progressivement quelque chose en l'utilisant.

Par exemple, j'*utilise* un clavier (je *me sers d'*​un clavier — en anglais « *I use a keyboard* ») pour taper ce message. Certes, j'*use* ce clavier (en anglais « *I wear down this keyboard* »), mais à un rythme imperceptible : je peux taper des milliers de messages sans que l'usure ne se fasse sentir. J'*utilise* un navigateur pour poster ce message ; comme c'est un logiciel, le fait de l'utiliser ne l'*use* pas.

On peut *user* quelque chose dont on ne dirait pas qu'on l'utilise. Par exemple, *user* la patience de quelqu'un signifie que l'on fait quelque chose qui l'irrite et tend à lui faire perdre patience.

Dans sa construction « **user de** quelque chose » ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/user) I), le verbe est à peu près synonyme de *utiliser*. Le terme *user de* met l'accent sur le fait qu'on a utilisé un objet, une méthode ou une personne dans un but précis. Il implique un choix délibéré. On peut souvent remplacer « user de » par « utiliser » ou « se servir de » en perdant éventuellement une petite nuance et le style littéraire mais sans changer fondamentalement le sens.

> Ce ne fut pas pour la recherche d'une volupté coupable et paresseuse qu'il commença à user de l'opium, […] (Baudelaire) [ou « à consommer de l'opium », voire « utiliser de l'opium »]

*User de* est en général neutre. Lorsqu'on l'utilise à propos d'une personne, il peut être négatif (par exemple, « user de ses relations » signifie que l'on cherche à obtenir quelque chose en demandant à des personnes que l'on connaît plutôt qu'en suivant la méthode officielle). Lorsque *user de* est opposer à *abuser de*, il est positif.

Answer (score 1):

Ce qui suit est renvoyée à http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=873708

> ♦ "Utiliser" is simply "to use"
>   ♦ "User" + de would be "to make use of" and would imply the deliberate use of something to achieve a goal.